# Func optional output parameters? C#

Tags: c#, sorting, optional-parameters

i'm trying to create a flexible insertion sort algorithm which will sort record object properties (months, days and times, mostly numeric data) so I'm passing Func delegate as a parameter to my insertion sort method, and these of course work well with my properties that are integers, but I also want to be able to perform same functionality on data such as doubles which could represent, magnitude, latitude, longitude etc.

Method overloading seems much too verbose for this instance, are there any other things I can utilize to achieve this flexibility?

Comment: Make your method generic and use `T` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to make it generic, and constrain the type to have a comparison:

```
public static void InsertionSort<T>(
    RecordCollection records, 
    Func<SesmicRecord, T> propertySelector)
    where T : IComparable<T>
```

Then just call `x.CompareTo(y)` when you need to compare values.

Or you could use a comparer:

```
public static void InsertionSort<T>(
    RecordCollection records, 
    Func<SesmicRecord, T> propertySelector, 
    IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    // Now use comparer.Compare(x, y) wherever you need to compare values
}
```

Or just use LINQ or existing BCL classes to do the sorting unless you *really* need to reimplement sorting yourself for some reason...

Comment: I'm practicing for the algorithms and complexities module, so I'm playing around with these sorting methods, without trying to use LINQ or any other integrated sorting functions.

Comment: Just implemented this solution, it seems like a new error occurred.  Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands type 'T' and 'T'. I tried researching IComparable, but the more I read about it, the less obvious it becomes for me how to implement it into my code.

Comment: @Vocaloidas: Well I did explicitly say "Then just call `x.CompareTo(y)` when you need to compare values." - in other words, you need to get rid of your `x < y` equivalents. For `x < y`, convert it to `x.CompareTo(y) < 0`, and the mirror for `>`. You don't need to implement `IComparable<T>` at all - the types already do that. You just need to *call* the comparison method in your code.

Comment: You're right, I should've read it more carefully. I already fixed. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to the following signature:

```
public static void InsertionSort<T>(RecordCollection RecordCollection, Func<SesmicRecord, T> properyField)
    where T: IComparable<T>
```

And now leverage the `IComparable<T>` interface: `t1.CompareTo(t2)`.